# How to examine contents of EFI partition in an ISO 9660 iso

Tags: uefi, iso, partition-table

I've tried converting a BIOS only iso to boot both BIOS and EFI without success. I believe the problem is the way the EFI is being built. How do I examine the EFI partition within the ISO9660 iso?

Results of fdisk -l

```
larry@larry-Satellite-C55-A:~/foxclone$ fdisk -l foxclone025-02.iso
Disk foxclone025-02.iso: 527 MiB, 552599552 bytes, 1079296 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x1b288083

Device              Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
foxclone025-02.iso1 *        0 1079295 1079296  527M  0 Empty
foxclone025-02.iso2        136    3015    2880  1.4M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
```

Build script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# The example names get mapped to their roles here
orig_iso="$HOME"/foxclone/foxclone025-01.iso
new_iso="$HOME"/foxclone/foxclone025-02.iso
new_files="$PWD"
mbr_template=/usr/lib/ISOLINUX/isohdpfx.bin


# Extract MBR template file to disk
dd if="$orig_iso" bs=1 count=432 of="$mbr_template"


# Create the new ISO image

xorriso -as mkisofs "$new_files" \
  -o "$HOME"/foxclone/foxclone025-02.iso \
  -isohybrid-mbr /usr/lib/ISOLINUX/isohdpfx.bin \
  -c isolinux/boot.cat \
  -b isolinux/isolinux.bin \
   -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table \
  -eltorito-alt-boot \
  -e isolinux/efiboot.img \
   -no-emul-boot \
   -isohybrid-gpt-basdat \
  -m grub.cfg
```

Thanks for any help you can provide,
Larry

Comment: Mount it. If you're on linux, `mount -o loop,offset=$((136*512)) foxclone025-02.iso /some/dir` as root. You can also use `kpartx`.

Comment: Thanks mosvy, that got it done.